# How to check if I'm in screen session?

Tags: gnu-screen, console

I need it to determine if hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> would disconnect me from server or just close current `screen`.

Is it somehow possible to check if I'm right now in `screen` session?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You can look at the `$STY` variable (a variable set by the [screen command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20991/8337)). If it is not "" then you are in a screen session.

I am in screen

```
$ echo $STY 
29624.pts-1.iain-10-04
$
```

I am not in screen

```
$ echo $STY

$
```

Comment: This presumes that you are still within a running session on the local computer.  If you start up screen and then SSH somewhere else, this won't work.

Comment: `if test -n "$STY"; then printf "This is a screen session named '$STY'.\n"; else printf "This is NOT a screen session.\n"; fi`

Comment: @DavidMackintosh if you're SSH'd into somewhere else, hitting ctrl-D will "disconnect me from server", which is exactly what the question asks about.

Comment: @aggregate1166877 I have this if you posted as an alias in every single machine that I use now.

Comment: This doesn't work in a `sudo` script run inside a screen

Answer (score 55):

You can look at the $TERM variable.

`echo $TERM`

If it's a `screen` session, the term variable should return "screen".

```
root@deore:/volumes# echo $TERM
screen
```

Ctrl-a -d (to exit screen)

```
root@deore:/volumes# echo $TERM
xterm
```

Also check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472287/how-do-you-tell-if-the-current-terminal-session-is-in-gnu-screen

Comment: This presumes that you are not deliberately messing with your TERM value for some reason.

Comment: If you're changing your TERM variable while inside screen, you're inviting all sorts of trouble on yourself.

Comment: Well my Solaris 2.6 nodes don't play nice with TERM values set to screen values.

Comment: `"$TERM" = "screen"` seems to be preserved when entering `sudo` environment, unlike the `$STY` option.

Answer (score 39):

Unless you have changed the default key bindings, you can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, which will show the time, if you are in screen. This will work even if you have ssh:d away somewhere else, unlike the other suggestions.

Comment: Why are we not upvoting this.

Comment: This is definitely the best solution here.

Comment: How is this the best solution?  What if you're *not* in screen, and `^A^T` is the key sequence for "nuke your homedir" in the program you're currently running?

Comment: @womble If you are in an unknown program that may do random destructive things as a response to key sequences and commands, then nothing is safe.

Comment: @AndreKR: It doesn't work in a script

Comment: im not upvoting because in in a screen, and screening into another screen, and i literally need to see if $STY is even set.  which for some reason its coming back empty.

Comment: Furthermore, this is not the best solution because this doesn't allow you to check this programmatically.

Answer (score 24):

The `caption` command in the `~/.screenrc` is a nice way to differentiate a screen session.

I'm personally using this:

```
$ cat ~/.screenrc
caption always "%{= kc}Screen session on %H (system load: %l)%-28=%{= .m}%D %d.%m.%Y %0c"
```

It adds a line like this one at the bottom of the screen:

```
Screen session on gbook (system load: 1,75 1,74 1,68)                   Lun 05.01.2015 13:01
```

With the first part (system name + load) in green and the date in pink. Useful and hard to miss!

Comment: This is perfect! It does not get in the way (bottom position), it is always visible (and colored) and provides useful info about system. I posted this here also http://stackoverflow.com/a/43571028/2450431

Comment: I'd like to add $STY in it. `caption always "%{= kc}Screen $STY on %H (system load: %l)%-28=%{= .m}%D %d.%m.%Y %0c"`

Answer (score 7):

I have found another solution:
Modify your `.screenrc`, so my screen session looks completely different from normal terminal.

Comment: I think I know what you're suggesting, and it could *in some situations* avoid this problem entirely. It might be more helpful if you describe what you mean by showing (e.g.) an example `.screenrc` file.

Answer (score 4):

Better answer (in my opinion), inspired by **[this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/422761/call-stack-of-shell-commands)**, just type the following:

```
pstree -s $$
```

If you get something like this:

```
systemd───sshd───sshd───bash───screen───screen───bash───pstree
```

… then you are in **screen**.

This is true not only for **screen**, but also for any kind of process (like **script**, nested **bash** or other shells) opening a nested shell, and this can even also show nested **screen** calls *(if several not consecutive occurrences exists)*.

Comment: This would be a good answer but it should be worked on further to allow scripting

Comment: Scripting was not asked inside initial question, but if really required:
  `if [[ $(pstree -s $$) =~ screen ]] ; then echo 'yes' ; else echo 'no' ; fi`

Comment: I would suggest `[[ $(pstree -sA $$) =~ ---screen--- ]]`, this will reduce the risk of a false  positive.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at a command line prompt, you can just type something, anything, and hit Ctrl+A. If your cursor jumps to the beginning of the prompt, you're not inside a screen. If you additionally have to hit A, then you are.

Answer (score -1):

Do a `screen -ls`. It's going to explicitly indicate `Attached` versus `Detached` status.

Example attached:

```
$ screen -ls | grep tached
3132.pts-0.esavo00      (Attached)
```

Example detached:

```
$ screen -ls |grep tached
3132.pts-0.esavo00  (Detached)
```

Comment: if there are screens attached somewhere else this might be an issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
screen -ls
```

to view your sessions and

```
screen -r sessioninfo
```

to reconnect to a disconnected one, if detached.

```
screen -D -r sessioninfo
```

to reconnect to a disconnected one.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.