# Is it possible to change GNU screen session name after created?

Tags: gnu-screen

[This continues my previous question [How do I know I'm running inside a linux "screen" or not?](https://serverfault.com/q/377221/41079) ]

As title, can I?

I tried `screen -S mysess` but it creates a new screen instead of changing the name of current screen.

I also tried `screen -X 'sessionname haha'` , but no effect. It just display a inverse-color bar at terminal bottom saying

```
-X: unknown command 'sessionname haha'
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> to get to command mode for the session and then use the `sessionname` command

```
sessionname session1
```

EDIT:

Using your example above:

If you are `detached` from a session you can change it's session name with

```
screen -r 25278.pts-15.linux-ic37 -X sessionname YourSessionName
```

If you are `attached` to the session then you can change it's session name with

```
screen -d -r 25134.pts-3.linux-ic37 -X sessionname YourSessionName
```

Comment: Iain, you're like Wikipedia with added mod privileges.  That's my cool-thing-I-did-not-know-but-will-use-often-now-I-do for the day, and it's not even 9am yet.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank. But I'd like it to be done programmably so to be run from a shell script, not interactively.

Comment: @JunChen: you should have said that in your question then !

Comment: Thank you. I got it now. The single quotes in my command caused the problem. Anyway, I think I have made it clear from the beginning, because from my screenshot, you can see I tried to change the session name via command line.

Comment: And I found that, in order to change *current* session name, just typing ``screen -X sessionname haha`` does not always work. On second execution, it will inevitably fail with message like ``/var/run/uscreens/S-chj2/16218.pts-9.linux-ic37: No such file or directory`` --still a pending question.