# GNU screen, how to get current sessionname programmatically

Tags: gnu-screen

[ This can be considered step 2 of my previous question [Is it possible to change GNU screen session name after created?](https://serverfault.com/q/377270/41079) ]

Actually, I'd like to write a script that can display current screen session name and change current session name.

For example:

```
sren armcross
```

It will change the session name to `armcross` (ARM gcc cross compiler) and output something like:

```
screen session name changed from '25278.pts-15.linux-ic37' to 'armcross'
```

So, the key question now is how to get current session name. Not only for display the old session name, but according to [Is it possible to change GNU screen session name after created?](https://serverfault.com/q/377270/41079) , I have to know it(pass to -d -r) before I can change it to something else.

Can we use `$STY` for current session name? No. `$STY` will not change after you have changed the session name to a user-defined one. However, for command

```
screen -d -r <oldsessname> -X sessionname armcross
```

＜oldsessname＞ should be the user-defined name(if ever defined) instead of `$STY`, otherwise, screen spouts error "No screen session found."

Maybe, there is a verbose way, use `screen -list` to list all sessions(user-defined name listed), then, match the pid part from $STY against those listed sessions and we will find current session's user-defined name. It should not be so verbose for such a straightforward question. Don't you think so?

The -d -D and -r -R options seems to expose too much implementation detail to screen's user. It seems, to rename a session, you have to detach it, then do the rename, then reattach it. Right?

My env: opensuse 11.3, GNU screen 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

could you try this one;

`screen -d -r $(ps -o ppid -p $$ --no-headers) -X sessionname newsessionname`

Comment: +1 from me. Thank you. If there is suitable chance, I'll try it. But for now, I've turn to tmux.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that when you set the `sessionname` manually screen changes the name of the relevant file in `/var/run/screen/S-$USER/` but doesn't update the value of `$STY` which would be ideal.

We can still use the original value of `$STY` to get the current session's name though as `$STY` contains the `PID` that relates to this sessionname.

```
PID=$(echo $STY | awk -F"." '{ print $1}')
```

You can then use the `PID` to get the sessionname from /var/run/screen/S-$USER

```
SESSIONNAME=$( ls /var/run/screen/S-$USER/$PID* | awk -F"." '{print $2}' )
```

Now you have the sessionname in `SESSIONNAME` you can do what you want with it.

Comment: Allow me some time to understand how your command works. Thanks.